# Error al tratar de actualizar contraseña de recuperación PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php7, md5

Estoy haciendo un nuevo código que ayuda al usuario a generar una nueva contraseña de recuperación al olvidar la suya. Esta es enviada a través de su correo electrónico, pero por algun motivo mi consulta sql **UPDATE actualiza la contraseña sin encriptar** Pero al ser envíada por mail esta **Si esta encriptada**...¿Algún consejo?

html:

```
  <form action="recuperar.php" method="POST">
            <div class="container">
                <h5 for="recuperar">Correo Electrónico:</h5>
                <input class="form-group col-md-6" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Email">&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Enviar">Recuperar</button>
                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Ingresa tu email de registro al sistema y recibirás un correo electrónico con tu contraseña nueva.</small><br><br><br>
                <a href="login.php" class="btn btn-info">Regresar</a>
            </div>
  </form>
```

recuperar.php

```
<?php

try{
if(isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email'])){

    if(isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email'])){
            $caracteres = '123AN*xk78acc994';
        for($x = 0; $x < 1; $x++){
            $pass = substr(str_shuffle($caracteres), 0, 8);
            $mail = $_POST['email'];
    }

    $mail = $_POST['email'];

            //Conexion con la base
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "mydb");
            // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "Update empresasregistradas Set password='$pass' Where email='$mail'";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "usuario modificado correctamente ";
    } else {
        echo "Error modificando: " . $conn->error;
    }

    require_once("PHPMailer-5.2.11/PHPMailerAutoload.php");

        //Nuevo correo electronico.
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.office365.com';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;

    $mail->Username = "my@mail.com";
    $mail->Password = "psw";
    $mail->setFrom('my@mail.com', 'Sistema NOM035 by CoreGroupSolutions');
    $mail->addAddress($usuario);
        //Titulo email.
    $mail->Subject = "Nueva Contraseña Sistema NOM035";
        //Cuerpo email con HTML.
        $mail->Body = "Tu contraseña actualizada es: ". $pass; 

        //Comprobamos el envio.
        if(!$mail->send()) {                    
            $error = "Ocurrió un error inesperado con él envió del correo electrónico, inténtelo de nuevo más tarde, disculpa las molestias.";
            echo'<script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Ocurrió un error inesperado con él envió del correo electrónico, inténtelo de nuevo más tarde, disculpa las molestias.");
            window.location.href="recupera.php";
            </script>'; 
        } else {
            $error = "Se envio correctamente el correo electrónico.";
            echo'<script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Se ha enviado el correo electrónico con su nueva contraseña.");
            window.location.href="recupera.php";
            </script>';

        } 
    }else echo 'Informacion incompleta';
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Excepción capturada: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}

?>
```

Comment: ¿Qué valor tiene `$pass` después de tu validación `isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email'])`?

Comment: @Fernando Torres Qué se ingrese un email valido para posteriormente saber si existe en la Base de Datos.